# Good backend way to store song (audio) samples for iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, video, backend

I need suggestions for a good way to store backend song previews (right now looking at itunes and maybe spotify and soundcloud). The idea is that I need to pre-download and maybe cache the 30-second and less audio files with easy recall.

Then I need a good way of overlaying the audio preview to a user video quickly and generating a new asset for that.

I imagine there are already good libraries for these tasks.

I'm thinking S3 right now for storage? Maybe that or something else? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of microservices that might help: [audio](https://api.microfabrik.com/audio) and [video](https://api.microfabrik.com/video) if you're ok using a mBAAS.